# rails 4 + mina deployment failure

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

i am deploying a rails 4 application using mina deployment. my deployment script is as

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)

set :domain, 'someplace.com'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/projects/website'
set :repository, 'git@github.com:someone/repo.git'
set :branch, 'master'

set :identity_file, "#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa"
set :user, 'deploy'    # Username in the server to SSH to.

set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/credentials.yml', 'log', 'tmp']

task :environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.1.0@default]'
end

task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit 'shared/config/database.yml'."]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/credentials.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit 'shared/config/credentials.yml'."]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'

    to :launch do
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end
end
```

when i deploy as 'mina deploy', i get error as

```
...

Symlinking shared paths
$ mkdir -p "./config"
$ mkdir -p "."
$ rm -rf "./config/database.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/config/database.yml" "./config/database.yml"
$ rm -rf "./config/credentials.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/config/credentials.yml" "./config/credentials.yml"
$ rm -rf "./log"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/log" "./log"
$ rm -rf "./tmp"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/tmp" "./tmp"

-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
$ mkdir -p "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/bundle"
$ mkdir -p "./vendor"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/projects/website/shared/bundle" "./vendor/bundle"
$ bundle install --without development:test --path "./vendor/bundle" --binstubs bin/ --deployment

...

Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle

-----> Precompiling asset files
$ RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/deploy/projects/website/tmp/build-138935597031149/tmp
/home/deploy/projects/website/tmp/build-138935597031149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:25:in `[]='
/home/deploy/projects/website/tmp/build-138935597031149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:34:in `cache_set'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that shared/tmp directory is created if not ssh into the server and

```
$ mkdir /home/deploy/projects/website/shared/tmp
```

make sure you have the right permissions too.
drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 1):

If you are symlinking your tmp directory ensure that it exists. If it doesn't the broken symlink will cause the same issue.